# Linux setfacl puzzle

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

I have a strange issue with some ACL I set for my VMs. 
My Vms are stored in the directory /shared/vms. The ACLs for this directory are:

```
getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:qemu:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:qemu:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

For some reason that I truly cannot understand, my latest VM has no permissions for qemu:

```
getfacl ./demo.qcow2 
# file: demo.qcow2
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
user:qemu:rwx                   #effective:---
group::rwx                      #effective:---
mask::---
other::---
```

The root user umask is the very liberal 0022. The desktop user that I use for the virt-manager has a little more restrictive 0007. But, those should not create an effective mask of --- !!!

So, why do I have those effective permissions?

Answer (score 0):

The effective mask is calculated by doing a bitwise `AND` between the permissions and the mask.  Since your mask is `---`, all permission bits will be turned off for any custom ACL entries you create.  To fix this you will need to set the mask to `rwx` like this:

```
setfacl -m m::rwx ./demo.qcow2
```

Repeat this for any files which are showing effective permissions that are not what you want.  Normally the mask is recalculated any time the ACL is changed, but this file may have been created with the `--no-mask` option, or something may have explicitly set the mask.

Comment: Please check again the OP. The directory has rwx as a default mask.

Comment: The VM file (which perhaps was created before the directory ACL was in place?), however, has a mask of `---`, which I believe is why the permission is effectively `---`.